# How can I convert this git filter-branch command from tree-filter to index-filter?

Tags: git, git-filter-branch

I am merging several repositories into a single repository, and we would like to keep history and some (shared) branches. There are going to be filename conflicts, so I am moving the contents of each individual repository into a subdirectory in the combined repository. I've tried a bunch of different filter-branch commands, and here is what I'm using:

```
$ shopt -s dotglob
$ git filter-branch --tree-filter 'mkdir <Subdirectory>; git mv -k * <Subdirectory>' --tag-name-filter cat --prune-empty -- --all
```

It is fairly slow (hours), and I need to do it a few more times. What should I replace the `mkdir ...; git mv ...` portion with so that I can use `index-filter` instead? Most of the examples I can find for index-filter only use `git rm`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is silly. I had tried the following, and it did work quickly, but it *copied* rather than *moving*. But I tried it again and it worked, so I guess I did something weird the first time.

```
$ git filter-branch --index-filter 'git ls-files -s | sed "s-\t\"*-&Subdirectory/-" | GIT_INDEX_FILE=$GIT_INDEX_FILE.new git update-index --index-info && mv "$GIT_INDEX_FILE.new" "$GIT_INDEX_FILE"' --tag-name-filter cat -- --all
```